# How to send multi-dimensional arrays in an HTML form to request?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have form to send products id with qty for each product my form:

```
 <select name="products[][product_id]">
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <option value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->trade_name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<input type="text" name="products[][quantity]">
```

With this `name` style I got like this:

```
"products" => array:4 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
    "product_id" => "1"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
    "quantity" => "2"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [▼
    "product_id" => "2"
    ]
    3 => array:1 [▼
    "quantity" => "3"
    ]
]
```

I need to achieve the array like this:

```
"products" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
        "product_id" => "1",
        "quantity" => "2"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
        "product_id" => "2",
        "quantity" => "3"
    ]
]
```

Comment: you would need to use some type of key in the empty brackets `products[0][product_id']` and `products[0][quantity]` so they will be in the same array

Comment: @lagbox that's my problem I can't use keys for it, because the from is dynamic and I can not control of how many products the user like add in one time

Comment: How do you loop these fields to make them dynamic?

Comment: @pktharindu it's simple jquery code by (append) my inputs like when the user click on plus icon the inputs added to the form!

Comment: you can use keys for it, if this is dynamic that means there is something that has the capability to store values in variables and increment them

Comment: @lagbox any example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name="products[product_id][]">
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <option value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->trade_name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<input type="text" name="products[quantity][]">
```

If you specify the keys first, and then create a nested array for those (opposite to what you have done) then when you need to access them you can loop through them and access the corresponding entry e.g

```
$combined_array = [];
foreach($request->products['product_id'] as $key => $value) {
   $combined_array[] = [
          'product_id' => $value,
          'quantity' => $request->products['quantity'][$key]
        ];
}
```

`$combined_array` should then have your data.

Comment: You don't use `$_POST` in Laravel, there's a `$request` object for that. Your code should be `foreach($request->input('products')['product_id'] as $key => $value`, then `'quantity' => $request->input('products')['quantity'][$key]`. Or `$request->products[...]`, etc etc.

Comment: thanks @TimLewis - i hadn't noticed the tag for laravel and it's not mentioned in the question!  Worth noting for anyone not using laravel that the point is to loop through your array, however you come by it in your framework

Comment: Yup! Fair point. And my comment wasn't to say that `$_POST` won't work, cause it will, but simply you should use the framework conventions :)

Comment: yeah I got it :) Thanks for the spot, OP might have gone down a slightly confused path without it (though hopefully they get the general idea!)

Comment: That's cool answer and doing what I need. I just asked cuz I thought there is another way to achieve this without using PHP code. anyway thank you so much :)

Comment: You could of-course use what @lagbox suggested and dynamically add that index through Jquery.

Comment: @pktharindu can you pls provide an example ?